# how to use DateTimePicker (MUI) with YupValidation and restrict startdate to come after enddate and enddate come before startdate?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datetimepicker, yup, use-form

This is my Current code:

```
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import { DateTimePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers";
```

```
const schema = Yup.object({
  startDate: Yup.date().required("startDate is required"),
  endDate: Yup.date().required("endDate is required"), 
});
```

```
const {
    register,
    control,
    formState: { errors },
    handleSubmit,
    reset,
    watch,
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {      
      startDate: "",
      endDate: "",
    },
    mode: "all",
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });
```

```
 const onSubmit = (data: any) => {  
    data.startDate = new Date(data.startDate).toISOString();
    data.endDate = new Date(data.endDate).toISOString();
  };
```

```
<div className="grid grid-cols-4 ml-10 mr-56">
        <div>
          <Controller
            name="startDate"
            control={control}
            render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
              <DateTimePicker
                disablePast
                id="startDate"
                label=" Start Date"
                placeholder="Start Date"
                value={value}
                onChange={onChange}
                renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
              />
            )}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <Controller
            name="endDate"
            control={control}
            render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
              <DateTimePicker
                disablePast
                label=" End Date"
                id="endDate"
                placeholder="End Date"
                value={value}
                onChange={onChange}
                renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}     
              />
            )}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
```

[start & end date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Twnnw.png)

(right now the validaiton works i just want to restrict the user from selecting end date before start date and vice versa)

right now i can choose date before the start date in the end date so how can i dont allow it(its important for me to make the dateformat UTC)
how can i solve this problem?

i tried to change it to textField
and date picker
tried to use dayjs but didnt work so i dont know what to do
cause i need validation too
(right now the validaiton works i just want to restrict the user from selecting end date before start date and vice versa)